# Android app - Perfomance vs Size

Tags: android, performance, postgis

I'm in a dilemma that somebody may know the best answer. I'm developing an app, that uses a geographic database to get points and current user position. The database that I'm using is PostGis and has 75MB of size. What do you think that fits best :

1. Develop a webservice and every 5meters do an http request to get user's position?
2. Use the database inside of the android and get geo information with queries?

Thanks ;-)

Comment: Would you download a 75+MB app from the PlayStore ? You probably want your app to build the database progressively. And you can consider adding a settings "use offline" that download the entire database.

Comment: My guess is you don't need all 75 MB of data at all times. Why not query the db when the app starts up with the user's current position and grab all necessary data at that time?

Comment: @pdegand59 and dcharms, I think your two answers combines each other. My DB is a map so, to grab data and build the android's database I'll need a web service, to connect my database and retrieve DB's data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the purpose of your app.

1. If your app requires the ability to be offline and still function, then obviously the database is required.
2. If your app does not require offline ability and the data being passed is small, then a service is a good option. If the data is large, then you are back to the database option.

We have had some real challenges with positioning data and the relative accuracy within our app. Another consideration is battery consumption. If you add messaging to GPS polling, it can suck up a lot of battery. Good luck.

Comment: that's it.. My goal is to optimize battery consumption! I don't know what is worst,  GPS + HTTP all the time (battery problem) or GPS + Queries all the time (Android app size and a bit consumption to)